# Read char by Char from File in C++ but not reading full file

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atOA4.jpg)I am trying to read File which has Ascii data inside file. It deosnt read full file and stops in between(when I checked in file by converting to Hex format, it shows it get stop when enters 0x1a). Below is my code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

      ifstream infile;
      char c;

       infile.open("test.txt");

       while(!(infile.eof())){

             infile.get(c);

             cout<< c;

       }

return 0;

}
```

Please suggest me how to read entire file(data inside file is in ascii format)?. Thanks in advance

Text File data :  ¯µbë                          éÿïÿ      ¬F¸

The reading has stopped reading after ey.

Comment: btw, `ifstream::get()` expects a reference to the `char` as a parameter.

Comment: How long is `test.txt`? Can you reproduce the problem with a short file (a few lines)? If so, include the content of that file in the question, and also show the output.

Comment: 0x1A is not a printable ASCII character. Are you sure the input file is ASCII text?

Comment: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: yes it is ascii text. example of file is µbƒ                           éÿ üÿÿüÿ            ÿÿîÿeÚ´  ïÿ    .

Comment: file size is 48kb only.

Comment: There is no `é` or `ÿ` in ASCII. This is not ASCII text. It might not be the cause of the problem, but it means your question is not accurate.

Comment: Try and reproduce the problem with a 10 byte file -- just trim it down to the part where you see it fail. Then copy/paste the whole 10 bytes into the question (not a comment) and also copy/paste the console output when you run the program. Then we have a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: ... and if you can't reproduce the problem in a 10 byte file, explain the details of that in the question.

Comment: `0x1A` or `Ctrl-Z` can be seen as end-of-file in Windows (which I'm guessing you're using) when a file is opened in "text mode". Try opening the file in _binary_ mode (I think by using `ios_base::binary` as the second parameter to `open`).

Comment: Yes I have changed to binary mode and it is working fine. Thanks tripeHound